# Jquery setting limits for the effect (margin-left)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set max and min limits on my navigation menu. So far I've code that works quasi perfectly...

```
var navmenuliwiwdth = 0;

$('#othermenu ul li').each(function() {
    navmenuliwiwdth += $(this).outerWidth();
});

$('#otherleftarrow').click(function() {
    if ( parseInt($('#othermenu ul').css('margin-left')) < 0 )
        $('#othermenu ul').animate({'margin-left': '+=50'}, 200);
    return false; 
});

$('#otherrighttarrow').click(function() {
    if ( navmenuliwiwdth > 638 && parseInt($('#othermenu ul').css('margin-left')) > (638 - navmenuliwiwdth))
        $('#othermenu ul').animate({'margin-left': '-=50'}, 200);
    return false;
});
```

​Right arrow limit works pefrctly. But left one misbehaves very often... it goes to 50px margin if I click right arrow fast and than click left arrow few times without waiting for the slider. I wonder why this happens and if there is any way to fix it, I understand it has something to do with `< 0`

Any ideas?

I was working here: http://jsfiddle.net/sandrodz/TsGqU/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set a `.stop()` method in jQuery to stop and clear the animation queue or else it will show an anormal behaviour while clicking the elements fast enough.

<strike>http://jsfiddle.net/TsGqU/4/</strike>
http://jsfiddle.net/TsGqU/7/

For further reading refer to the jQuery API http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Edit: I just added another condition so the animation will not trigger as long as the last animation is running. You can check a running animation with $([selector]).is(':animated'). This method returns a bool.

Comment: Even with stop, I managed to go very fast clicking first right arrow than left arrow and I managed to go left beyond margin:0. I'm sure problem is <0 rather than stop. http://jsfiddle.net/sandrodz/TsGqU/5/

Comment: I see, this one works perfectly. So you check if animation is not running... perfect!